# how to make popover arrow higher and thinner using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the arrow in popover using bootstrap higher and thinner.

What i make is below:

[image]

But what i want is below:

[image]

Anyone could give me a hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I change it by adding below code:

```
.popover > .arrow:after {
border-top-color: #345478 !important;
border-width:10px 7px 0 7px;
}
```